# Join for a SQL Query - Can't write a Query for Getting Countries with the help of IPs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of visitors whose IPs I have recorded. Now for a specific report, I need to see which country each visitor has come from.

I divided this task into two part, first getting all the IPs of the user who have uniquely logged in and the second part is to search two tables with country/IP information (from ip2nation) and to get the country with the provided IP.

### First Part - getting all the IPs of the user who have uniquely logged in

```
SELECT
     a.uid, a.hostname, a.timestamp, 
 COUNT(*) AS times
FROM
  login_activity a
GROUP BY
  a.hostname
ORDER BY
  times desc
```

This gave me IPs (hostname) of all the past-logged in users. Works fine.

### Second Part - Get country from the two tables (both have thousands of records) by inputting IP

```
SELECT 
    c.country
FROM 
    ip2nationCountries c, ip2nation i
WHERE 
    i.ip < INET_ATON(  "157.191.122.36" ) 
AND 
    c.code = i.country

ORDER BY i.ip DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This works great too.

Now, for the real problem. Joining these two queries, to get the country (instead of an IP) from all the logged in users. This is what I wrote:-

```
        SELECT
         a.uid, a.hostname, a.timestamp, c.country, 
         COUNT(*) AS times
        FROM
          login_activity a, ip2nationCountries c, ip2nation i
        WHERE
           i.ip < INET_ATON(a.hostname)     
           AND c.code = i.country

        GROUP BY
          a.hostname
        ORDER BY
          times desc;
```

This has two problems:-

- it takes a lot of time to load.
- it gives wrong data (showing the visits in thousands for each row).
- Basically, it shows all the data wrong.

Could you help me in making this SQL?

Just in case, the structure/data of the tables are below:-

### Structure/Data of the Tables is :-

### **ip2nation** (has a lot of data)

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE ip2nation (
  ip int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  country char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  KEY ip (ip)
);
```

(Data)

```
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(0, 'us');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(687865856, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(689963008, 'eg');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691011584, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691617792, 'zw');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691621888, 'lr');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691625984, 'ke');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691630080, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691631104, 'gh');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691632128, 'ng');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691633152, 'zw');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691634176, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691650560, 'gh');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691666944, 'ng');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691732480, 'tz');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691798016, 'zm');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691863552, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(691994624, 'zm');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692011008, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692027392, 'mg');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692035584, 'ao');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692043776, 'na');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692060160, 'eg');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692191232, 'ci');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692207616, 'za');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692240384, 'gh');
INSERT INTO ip2nation (ip, country) VALUES(692256768, 'sd');
```

### **ip2nationCountries** (has a lot of data)

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE ip2nationCountries (
  code varchar(4) NOT NULL default '',
  iso_code_2 varchar(2) NOT NULL default '',
  iso_code_3 varchar(3) default '',
  iso_country varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  country varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  lat float NOT NULL default '0',
  lon float NOT NULL default '0',  
  PRIMARY KEY  (code),
  KEY code (code)
);
```

(Data)

```
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ad', 'AN', 'AND', 'Andorra', 'Andorra', 42.3, 1.3);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ae', 'AR', 'ARE', 'United Arab Emirates', 'United Arab Emirates', 24, 54);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('af', 'AF', 'AFG', 'Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 33, 65);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ag', 'AT', 'ATG', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 17.03, -61.48);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ai', 'AI', 'AIA', 'Anguilla', 'Anguilla', 18.15, -63.1);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('al', 'AL', 'ALB', 'Albania', 'Albania', 41, 20);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('am', 'AR', 'ARM', 'Armenia', 'Armenia', 40, 45);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('an', 'AN', 'ANT', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'Netherlands Antilles', 12.15, -68.45);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ao', 'AG', 'AGO', 'Angola', 'Angola', -12.3, 18.3);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('aq', 'AT', 'ATA', 'Antarctica', 'Antarctica', -90, 0);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('ar', 'AR', 'ARG', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', -34, -64);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('as', 'AS', 'ASM', 'American Samoa', 'American Samoa', -14.2, -170);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('at', 'AU', 'AUT', 'Austria', 'Austria', 47.2, 13.2);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('au', 'AU', 'AUS', 'Australia', 'Australia', -27, 133);
INSERT INTO ip2nationCountries (code, iso_code_2, iso_code_3, iso_country, country, lat, lon) VALUES('aw', 'AB', 'ABW', 'Aruba', 'Aruba', 12.3, -69.58);
```

### **login_activity**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mslop_login_activity` (
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for an activity (session).',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The mslop_users.uid corresponding to a session, or 0 for anonymous user.',
  `host_user_agent` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '$_SERVER["HOST_USER_AGENT"] string. This can be used with get_browser() in PHP.',
  `hostname` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The IP address that was used for this session.',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The UNIX timestamp when the session was started.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`),
  KEY `aid` (`aid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

(Data)

```
INSERT INTO `mslop_login_activity` (`aid`, `uid`, `host_user_agent`, `hostname`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363038356),
(2, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363038374),
(3, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363193841),
(4, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363194789),
(5, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363197889),
(6, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363207361),
(7, 35, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363301612),
(8, 35, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363301751),
(9, 1, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363364574),
(10, 1, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363374517),
(11, 1, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363377701),
(12, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363714792),
(13, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363714911),
(14, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17', '172.24.1.143', 1363714929),
(15, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363715946),
(16, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10', '172.24.1.161', 1363791080),
(17, 4, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10', '172.24.1.161', 1363791124),
(18, 1, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10', '172.24.1.161', 1363791144),
(19, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22', '172.24.1.143', 1363791365),
(20, 64, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22', '172.24.1.143', 1363791650);
```

---

I changed the query as follows, but it still is showing me wrong results ...

Could you guys have a look:-

```
SELECT l.uid,
    l.hostname,
    l.timestamp,
    c.country,
    l.times
FROM ip2nationCountries c
JOIN ip2nation i ON c.code = i.country
JOIN ( SELECT
        a.uid,
        a.hostname,
        MAX(a.timestamp) AS timestamp,
        COUNT(*) AS times
    FROM mslop_login_activity a
    WHERE a.uid = 3
    AND a.hostname = "157.191.122.36"
    GROUP BY a.hostname) AS l ON i.ip < INET_ATON( l.hostname )
```

Comment: A big part of the problem is that `WHERE i.ip < INET_ATON(a.hostname)` has to be evaluated once for each row, and search condition is practically guaranteed to be wrong almost all the time. Edit your question, and paste the structure of your tables and some sample data as INSERT statements.

Comment: Just updated. Thanks.

Comment: SQL, please, not images. We can't copy and paste an image into a local database for testing.

Comment: Done, Thanks a lot Mike. Let me know if there is anything else, I could do.

Comment: The problem here is `i.ip < INET_ATON( l.hostname )`. ip2nation's original query uses `LIMIT` in conjuction with `ORDER BY` to retrieve first ip smaller than the one requested. You are getting multiple matches because you cannot specify that you want only one record from a join. To solve write your summary query with grouping logic **not using country info** and then use subquery to retrieve missing information using `ORDER BY DESC` and `LIMIT`. This is certainly not the fastest solution, but it will be accurate. Better solution would be to redesign ip2nation table to include ip ranges.

Comment: (continued) as in Mike's answer, not using a view but new, indexed table. After all, you only download ip2nation database now and then, and you can prepare procedure which would convert it to more query-friendly format.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a join.  This would be much more obvious if you used proper join syntax, so take this as a lesson and always use `join` and `on` clauses in the future.

The query you want:

```
    SELECT a.uid, a.hostname, a.timestamp, c.country, COUNT(*) AS times
    FROM login_activity a left outer join
         ip2nationCountries c
         on a.hostname = c.ip left outer join
         ip2nation i
         on i.ip < INET_ATON(a.hostname) AND c.code = i.country
    GROUP BY a.hostname
    ORDER BY times desc;
```

Two comments.  I made these `left outer join`s.  If there are hostnames with no match, then they will still appear in the output (change to `inner join` if you want to filter these out).  Second, you might want to pre-aggregate the `login_activity` table if it is really big, before joining in the other tables.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for taking out the time to answer my question. There is one problem though. On this line, on a.hostname = c.ip left outer join, the ip column doesn't exist in this table (ip2nationCountries). It exists in ip2nation table. Hence even if I change c to i, it still can't find it. Any idea, how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: "so take this as a lesson and always use join and on clauses in the future."
I disagree. There are many scenarios where a join is an overkill and a sub select a much better option. I would suggest you to withdraw the 'always'.

Comment: But guys, I'll be grateful if you could help me with the comment I wrote above ... :(

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the user id, the hostname, and the number of times they're logged on that host.

```
SELECT a.uid, a.hostname, COUNT(*) AS times
FROM mslop_login_activity a
GROUP BY  a.uid, a.hostname
ORDER BY  times desc
```

To simplify getting the country, use a view to compute the range. (This view is highly depedent on your having accurate and complete data about how IP addresses map to countries. I didn't try to verify your data.)

```
create view ip_range as 
select t1.ip as ip_start
        , (select min(ip) - 1 from ip2nation where ip > t1.ip) ip_end
        , t1.country
from ip2nation t1
```

Now you should be able to use a simple, obvious join to get the country.

```
SELECT a.uid
          , a.hostname
          , inet_aton(a.hostname) as ip_int
          , ip_range.country
FROM mslop_login_activity a
inner join ip_range
on inet_aton(a.hostname) between ip_range.ip_start and ip_range.ip_end
```

With your sample data, this will return no rows. For one thing, all your IP addresses for login activity are in a [reserved range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).  For another, the longest IP address (integer) in "ip2nation" is 9 digits; that's not enough digits.  My own IP address converts to a 10-digit integer.

If I update one of your IP addresses in login activity to a US IP address that converts to an integer of 9 digits, the query above correctly identifies the country as "US".

---

This is one of your original queries. It doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

```
SELECT
     a.uid, a.hostname, a.timestamp, 
 COUNT(*) AS times
FROM
  login_activity a
GROUP BY
  a.hostname
ORDER BY
  times desc
```

It returns this row.

```
uid  hostname      timestamp  times
--
3    172.24.1.143  1363038356 20
```

But this query returns 12 rows. Note that 12 rows doesn't equal 20 times.

```
SELECT uid
FROM mslop_login_activity 
where uid = 3
```

Using GROUP BY in MySQL is dangerous unless you know what you're doing and your'e really, really careful. (I don't think *any* other dbms will run your original first query, because it's not conformant SQL.)

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks a lot for your assistance. When I try to create this view, the system hangs up; as in goes into continuous working mode; and even becomes inactive. Probably due to large data? Do you think you could download the country data directly from this site (http://www.ip2nation.com/) and I can send you the records from my small table. In this way, you can test the query thoroughly?

Comment: Hi Mike,If you could please check the SQL you mentioned with the data at ipnation.com, I will be very thankful. If you like, I could compensate you for your efforts. I am checking the data with my IP at 157.191.122.36 (See the query below). If you still need data for the table (login_activity), let me know.

Comment: @Steve: ipnation.com is a parked domain. I think your IP addresses (integers) in ip2nation are wrong or incomplete. One of ibm.com's IP addresses (129.42.38.1) [converts](http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/ipcalc) to 2167023105, which is a 10-digit number. You don't have anything longer than a 9-digit number in "ip2nation".

Comment: Hi Mike, the view you created up hangs the phpmyadmin for some reason. I think it's not stable. Is there a posibility that we could just make a Query without a view?

Comment: Yes, but you're probably better off cutting down your data so you can use the view for testing. (Because your sample data isn't right.) When your query is right, you can replace the ip2nation table with a table that has the same structure as the view.